# PHP change row based on <select> value

Tags: php, html

I want to have a  input that can change the value of a row in my database. (mysqli)
For example:

if option 1 is selected, the row will change in the value of option 1. 
And if option 2 is selected, the row will change in the value of option 2. 
How do i do that?
My code of the inc. file:

```
if(isset($_POST['adjust-groep'])) {
    $sqlGroep = 'UPDATE employee set groep=? WHERE ID=?';
    $stmtGroep = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
    if(!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmtGroep, $sqlGroep)) {
        echo 'MYSQLI statement mislukt';
    } else {
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmtGroep, "si", $newGroep, $id);
        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmtGroep);
        $resultGroep = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmtGroep);
        if(!$resultGroep) {
                header('Location: ../control.php?error=success');
                exit();            
        } else {
                header('Location: ../control.php?error=fail');
                exit();                
        }
    }
}
```

The other code of the select:

```
<form action="includes/controladjust.inc.php" class="form-group>
    <select name="adjust-Groep" class="custom-select" id="inputGroupSelect01">
        <option selected>Huidige groep: <?php echo $Groep  ?></option>
        <option name="Admin" value="2">Admin</option>                                
        <option name="user" value="3">user</option>                                
    </select>
    <button type="submit" name="adjust-groep" class="mt-2 btn btn-success">groep wijzigen</button>   
</form>
```

With kind regards,

Comment: `mysqli_stmt_get_result()` There is no result set from an UPDATE. Just a TRU or FALSE to tell you it worked or failed.

Comment: So `$resultGroep =  mysqli_stmt_execute($stmtGroep);` will give you a boolean to test

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using select wrongly

```
<option value="admin">Admin</option>
```

You don't have to use name attribute on it, just set value and in php, if admin is selected `$_POST['adjust-groep']` will output admin, final code will be

```
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmtGroep, "si", $_POST['adjust-groep'], $id);
```